# How do I fill randomized shapes with color by clicking with processing and python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, processing

I made a grid of squares and was able to fill shapes with color by clicking because they were all the same size, but trying to do the same with inconsistent shapes created by intersecting lines has been much more challenging.

I made a small program which draws lines starting and ending at 15 specified points around a triangle. Here's a couple examples of what I get when I run it:
[image]
[image]

How can I fill one of these shapes within the triangle at a time, similar to the functionality of Microsoft Paint?

Comment: In my mind, I think that when you get the coordinates of where you clicked, you should first determine what side of each drawn line is concerned. Then you need to find the surface intercepting all theses surfaces. Are you working in vectorial or do you render everything as a pixel grid?

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I don't exactly know what those two terms mean, but I think it's a pixel grid, because in the setup, I typed: size(1000,1000) which seems like the code for the creation of a grid of pixels.

Comment: So if you have a grid of pixel this is simple: for each pixel you just have to check for each line if the pixel is in the same side of the line as the point on where you clicked. If for all lines the pixel meets this condition, then you can fill the pixel and so on.

Comment: Or another way: you start filling the pixel in black where you clicked, then for all 9 pixels around, if one pixel is white (or the selected color), you fill it in black and check the other ones around, etc, using a recursive function call. At the end, all the area will be colored and the functions will stop.

Comment: The term to use in Google to locate this is "flood fill". (Unrelated, but please look up the difference between vector and bitmap images. This is as important as the difference in real life between floor tiles and wall-to-wall carpet – the best to use depends on the shape and size of your floor.)

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois seems like a very slow algorithm. It might be more efficient to once and for all create an array of shapes, one for each region, which would allow you to set the fill in a single line of code (once you determine which of the shapes contains the mouse click).

Comment: @JohnColeman You're right. However even if you already know all shapes delimitations, you still have to find a way to determine which pixel is inside. You can tag every pixel as belonging to a shape, but that's memory-costly.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois I agree that tagging every pixel would be inefficient. As in your first  comment above, the appropriate shape would still be determined by what side of each line you are on. Since this is the python version of Processing, it might be natural to use a dictionary (rather than an array) of shapes where the keys are things which look like e.g. `'0010011'` with one character for each line. The mouse click event handler could build up the key in a loop, or perhaps just a `''.join( ... appropriate comprehension ...)`